# Cannot display google map after changing keystore

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, api-key, rsa-key-fingerprint

I had a workable map app, but after i changed the keystore, also create api key, and update it into my AndroidMenifest, the map was not display anymore,

and I found something interesting, that the certificate Fingerprint and api Key in error log are totally different as keystore and console api key I created.

My api key is AIzaSyA-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXJhfQCboM
and SHA1 is FE:CF:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:8A:0D

Here are my manifest below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/es100x100"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXJhfQCboM" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainFragmentActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Error log

```
Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: esoft.com.edm, API Key: AIzaSyBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_eSh-E, Certificate Fingerprint: 5BFD72xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxD031
The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

hope some one can let me figure out what I missed...

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that your API key is correct and is indeed the API key registered with the keystore that you have signed with, you could check a few things.

1. Did you change the package name of your app to something new? Then you would require to add a new entry for your new package name on the Google API console.
2. The API key is cached in the app. Even after changing it to a new one, and installing it, the app uses the old one for some time. You could try uninstalling and re-installing the app, and see if it helps.

Comment: I have checked and also tried to create a new project with new package, also register a new api key, and enable google map api v2, but the problem is still exist...btw why the new project still get the old api key and SHA1?

Comment: No, I meant, when you change the API key, and re-install the app over the existing one, containing the old API key.

Comment: when I install the app from Exlipse, the map is blank, but when i exprt sign apk, the map worked.....really annoyed...anw thanks Kunar Bibek

Comment: Installing from eclipse, signs it with a debug keystore, for which the API key would be wrong. You should also add your Debug keystore's SHA1, and then it should work when you install through eclipse as well.

Comment: add the debug keystore's SHA1 into menifest??

Comment: No, to Google's API console, like you must have done for your signing keystore.

Comment: okay...actually I did, but the map still blank when doing installation from eclipse...also get the old api key and SHA1 from error log...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the feature of "Google Maps Android API v2" in your console. Also make sure you have followed all the steps of configuration as shown [HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

[image]

Have you generated your API key by adding your SHA1 and appending your Package name as shown in image?

[image]

Like as below example:

> BE:03:E1:44:39:7B:E8:17:02:9F:7F:B7:98:82:EA:DF:84:D0:FB:6A;com.test.googlemapsv2